# Where can I find JsonFeedView.jsp for DXA 2.0

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-2.0, json

I am trying to access my DXA model data in JSON format by using the format=json query string parameter (as outlined in the [docs](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v10/GUID-C5D23B8A-6846-4187-9997-A9A1010D418E)). However I get an error displayed:

> HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
>
> Type Status Report
>
> Message /WEB-INF/Views/jsonFeedView.jsp
>
> Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

I have hunted around for this jsonFeedView.jsp but cannot find it anywhere - is this perhaps missing from DXA 2.0?

Answer (score 3):

Found the problem, an extra `UrlBasedViewResolver` bean is in place with `viewClass` `JstlView` and order 5. Because of this new `UrlBasedViewResolver` the `BeanNameViewResolver` is never reached. This is why we get HTTP Status 404 – Not Found.

Answer (score 1):

This is weird; for sure, the ability to retrieve A JSON representation by means of specifying `format=json` in the URL query string has not been removed in DXA 2.0 (as proven by automated regression tests).

I don’t know why you are getting that error, though.  AFAIK, the JSON representation does not use a JSP view, but my knowledge of the Java implementation is limited.

Comment: We are not using the core module, could it be that something from this module is required?

Comment: That could explain why we’re not observing this problem in-house, indeed.  Would of course be a defect if this is the case.